# Prevent Squid from caching on a specific path

Tags: linux, proxy, reverse-proxy, cache, squid

I'm using this rule in /etc/squid/squid.conf

```
acl DenyApp urlpath_regex /app/path1/path2
no_cache deny DenyApp
```

It's working great. However, what I would like to happen is for Squid to still cache /app/path1/path2/js,  /app/path1/path2/images, and  /app/path1/path2/fonts, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access controls are not limited to a single operation. Just create another ACL that matches the sub-paths you do want to cache, and use it to prevent the first ACL from marking those things as non-cacheable.

```
 acl exceptions urlpath_regex ^/app/path1/path2/(js|fonts|images)
 acl DenyApp urlpath_regex ^/app/path1/path2
 cache deny DenyApp !exceptions
```

This is all explained in the Squid FAQ http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/SquidAcl#Common_Mistakes

Comment: That's an amazing use of !exceptions! Never seen a config like that. Thanks!